# Missing type annotation for 'U'

Tags: flowtype

The following code works fine but I'm getting a Flow error for it:

```
    case UPDATE_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.map((user) => {
          if (user.id === action.id) {
            return {...user, [action.propName]: action.payload};
          } else {
            return user;
          }
        })
      };
    }
```

The exact message is this:

```
<U>(
  callbackfn: (
    value: User,
    index: number,
    array: Array<User>
  ) => U,
  thisArg?: any
) => Array<U>

any

Missing type annotation for `U`. `U` is a type parameter declared in  function type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at call of method `map` [2].Flow(InferError)
```

I suspect the problem might be related to the way I've defined my Action types for the Reducer:

```
type ToggleModalAction = {type: typeof TOGGLE_MODAL};
type CancelRequestAction = {type: typeof CANCEL_REQUEST, payload: boolean};
type UpdateCompanyAction = {type: typeof UPDATE_COMPANY, payload: number};
type ResetStateAction = {type: typeof RESET_STATE};
type AddUserAction = {type: typeof ADD_USER, isDirty: boolean};
type UpdateUserAction = {type: typeof UPDATE_USER, id: number, propName: string, payload: string | number};
type RemoveUserAction = {type: typeof REMOVE_USER, id: number};
```

I've tried several things to resolve it but none work.  Any ideas?

Comment: You have not provuded enough information. There should be more to that error explaining what `[1]` and `[2]` are. Your code snippet also doesn't tell us what the types of `state` or anything else is. Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've expanded my question to provide more info.  Might this help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to provide the return value for map

```
case UPDATE_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.map((user): User => {
          if (user.id === action.id) {
            return {...user, [action.propName]: action.payload};
          } else {
            return user;
          }
        })
      };
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand.  To be clear, the code works perfectly.  It's just that Flow is complaining about it.

Comment: I see. Try to provide the return type for callback that you pass in map as I did in my answer.

Comment: For some reason for me only add the return type of the callback function passed to map with the syntax described in the answer did not work. As described here https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6828 I had to pass the type like that: state.users.map<User>((user) => {